# Graceful restart of Apache may fail with avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst saying "Not supported"

Tags: apache2

It has now happened tice that my Apache 2.4.41 (on Ubuntu 20.04) automatically performs a graceful restart around midnight, but the previously running website doesn't "come back".
The relevant entries in /var/log/apache/error.log are

```
AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[:error] [pid 443511] avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("XXXXX") failed: Not supported
[:error] [pid 443511] avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst("XXXXX") failed: Not supported
```

where `XXXXX` is a valid fqdn under the `.de` top level domain (and I can only guess that the line occurs twice because it is once for http and once for https).

I don't know what really happens then: If I try a graceful restart by hand, it works without any problems. Searching for the "avahi_entry_group_add_service_strlst" message, I find only cases with other reasons, e.g. "Invalid host name" or "local name collision", but never "Not supported". Even less do I have an idea what could be the cause.

Comment: Avahi support in Apache comes from `mod_dnssd`.  See https://0pointer.de/blog/projects/mod_dnssd.html  Are you intentionally enabling this module and using its features?

Comment: I haven't had good luck with avahi on Ubuntu. It tries to auto detect my local network printer but causes the print dialog and applications to hang when you try to use that auto-detected printer. [How do I get rid of a ghost printer in Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676863/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-ghost-printer-in-gnome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the comment by *Stephen Ostermiller*, I did a

```
a2dismod dnssd
```

cause I have no idea why it was enabled on this box in the first place.

Comment: I figured that would be the solution if you weren't actually using the module. My guess is that the module is now enabled by default and Ubuntu. I've had to disable other modules after updates in the past.